# Adding &callback=? to jQuery function failing

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a JSON call that is cross site. If I use IE8 due to lower restrictions that Firefox it works without problem.

If I add &callback=? to the function it just dies. I can't even see the AJAX call being made in Firebug. Once this is added to the URL then both IE8 and Firefox die silently.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = 'http://www.example.com/PeopleSearch/?search=tim&callback=?';

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data)
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: what happens when you add callback=%3F

Comment: drop the dataType and the data attribute and try it

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - It doesn't treat it like JSONP. So it falls back to working in IE8 and not FF.

Comment: @JoeTuskan - If I remove those the AJAX call can be seen in Firebug, but an empty string is returned. Under these conditions it is working in IE8 so I assume it is falling back to a standard AJAX call and thus JSONP is not being used.

Comment: Can you give an example url which returns valid response for this url. Also, if you set your dataType to jsonp the callback will be appended to the url automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The more secure way of Ajax with Jquery :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = 'http://www.example.com/PeopleSearch';

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type : "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {"search":"tim","callback":""}, 
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data); //It will be something like [Object object,since it is encoded as json from the server side]
  },
  error: function(data) {
          alert(data);
  }
});
});

/******************SERVER SIDE****************/
//do stuff....
echo json_encode($result);exit;
```